# TabBar hides partially on phone/hangouts call

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

The image will be self explanatory, whenever I get a phone/hangouts call and get back to the app my TabBar hides a couple pixels below. Any suggestions to avoid this?

[image]

Comment: Are you using `UITabBarController`?

Comment: Yes I am, a subclass actually.